# SQL Select if DateTime is between some Time interval

Tags: sql, datetime, select, time, db2

I have table T1:

```
ID  SCHEDULE
1   2018-05-12 14:00:00
```

I have table T2

```
 SCHEDULESTART       SCHEDULEEND
 09:00                  17:00
```

I need to do the SELECT from T1 table.

I would like to get all the rows from T1 where TIME from the SCHEDULE field is between the time period (START and END from second table).

I am working in some IBM application where it is **only possible** to start with SQL statement after the WHERE clause from the first table T1.

So query (unfortunately) must always start with `"SELECT * FROM T1 WHERE..."`
This cannot be changed (please have that in mind).

This means that I cannot use some JOIN or UNION ALL statement after the `"FROM T1"` part because I can start to write SQL query only after the WHERE clause.

For this example it is OK to have the statement like this:

```
select TIME(SCHEDULE) from T1
where  TIME(SCHEDULE)>=(SELECT SCHEDULESTART FROM T2 ) 
AND    TIME(SCHEDULE)<=(SELECT SCHEDULEEND FROM T2)
```

and it will return correct result.

BUT,
if SCHEDULE is for example `2018-05-12 23:00:00` and `SCHEDULESTART is 22:00:00` and `SCHEDULEEND is 03:00:00` then this query will not work (which is logical because time is during the night and in period from switching from first day to second)!
Maximum time period which could be taken into calculation in T2 table is 24 hours time period (just for one day).

How exactly SQL query should be defined to cover all cases?
Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

This is a complicated example.  I would write your version as:

```
where EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM T2 WHERE TIME(T1.SCHEDULE) BETWEEN SCHEDULESTART AND SCHEDULEEND)
```

You can then modify this as:

```
where EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM T2
              WHERE (SCHEDULESTART <= SCHEDULEEND AND
                     TIME(T1.SCHEDULE) BETWEEN SCHEDULESTART SCHEDULEEND)
                    ) OR
                    (SCHEDULESTART > SCHEDULEEND AND
                     TIME(T1.SCHEDULE) NOT BETWEEN SCHEDULESTART AND SCHEDULEEND)
                    )
              );
```

Comment: Hi Gordon. Are you missing AND at first BETWEEN statement?.. Also is it with this covered all possible cases? I hope you understand me what is the issue? Thank you in advance

Comment: also I think that there are some parenthesis errors in your second example?

Comment: Consider EDGE case scenario....Since you are using `NOT BETWEEN`, `SCHEDULESTART` and `SCHEDULEEND` will not be considered. So, if `T1.SCHEDULE` is `22:00` it will return false for `NOT BETWEEN` `22:00`  AND `03:00`

Comment: Hi Rahul, Gordon. I also noticed some error. If DATETIME is 2018-05-12 23:30:00  and START is 23:31 and END is 03:00 this query returns result although it should not return it!!! So it seems that this is not working correctly.

Comment: @RahulJain . . . I don't think the question is clear on the "edge" cases.  The logic in this solution can be easily adapted to including or not including the end points.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
where 
EXISTS (
        SELECT 
            1
        FROM 
            T2
        WHERE 
            ( 
                SCHEDULESTART <= SCHEDULEEND 
            AND
                TIME(T1.SCHEDULE) BETWEEN SCHEDULESTART AND SCHEDULEEND
            )
        OR
            (
                SCHEDULESTART > SCHEDULEEND AND
                (
                    TIME(T1.SCHEDULE) NOT BETWEEN SCHEDULEEND AND SCHEDULESTART
                ) 
                OR 
                    TIME(T1.SCHEDULE) = SCHEDULESTART 
                OR 
                    TIME(T1.SCHEDULE) = SCHEDULEEND
            )
        );
```

Comment: error with parenthesis I think. Do you think this is now covering ALL cases?

Comment: Updated. I assume this will cover all the scenarios. But don't hesitate to test it yourself.